# Trying to create a bootable CD

Tags: mount, lubuntu, iso, cd-image

**Windows 10, brand new HP Laptop.**
Downloaded: lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.**torrent**
Tutorial says to right click and Mount>. Windows 10 does not know what this file is. If I rename it and drop, .torrent, extension Windows says it is corrupt.
*So, what do I do now?*

Comment: The ISO needs to be written to media for booting and installing.  See 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
or https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-windows/14008, or better yet refer to the Lubuntu manual Chapter 1 Installing Lubuntu... Chapter 1.1 Retrieving the image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html
Chapter 1.2 Booting the Image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html
Chapter 1.3 Installation - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html

Comment: FYI: The Lubuntu manual assumes 20.04 LTS, so screens will not match, and some options use different wording (a 'something else' install on 18.04 is referred to as "Manual Partitioning" but it's the same thing)... Lubuntu 18.04 LTS has most of a years support left? (2018-April + 3years), do you want to still use it past 2021-April? (and the i386 version?) as all later releases will require you to re-install (new LXQt desktop; 18.04 was last with legacy LXDE desktop).

Comment: Thank you. I did get clarity and downloaded the iso I wanted. Yes, I want rel. 18 right now. I was on 16 and I trashed it. Now I just want a OS to work and get me back on my feet. Updates will follow. And I have an older Laptop with 32Bit processing.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu is a desktop, and all server & desktop releases use the *yy.mm* format (they have multiple releases per year), compared to specialist releases that use *yy* (and are based on *snaps* thus different). Lubuntu's site is lubuntu.me, with downloads coming from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ where you'll note the various files (.torrent is tiny as it's a pointer to download the ISO only). Yes for x86/32-bit i686 (called i386 in debian/ubuntu) you do need 18.04 as later releases (18.10/19.04) are EOL (*end-of-life*)